# Ninject can't find any sources

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm fairly new with ninject, I was just following some tutorials and adding the code to my asp.net mvc 4 project and then i noticed that ninject can't find any sources of itself. It keeps asking me where all the source files are located. I'm not sure what's going on.

Edit: Even if i install the mvc 3 ninject package i still get the same problem. It opens a filedialog to let me select where the class files are for ninject.

Installed items:

- Ninject - ioC Container
- Ninject - Ninject.Web.Common

My NinjectDependencyResolver class:

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        kernel.Bind<IEmail>().To<Classes.Email.MockEmail>();
    }
}
```

Application_Start:

```
//Ninject
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver());
```

Source search information (error):

> Locating source for
>   'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\BindingRoot.cs'.
>   Checksum: MD5 {25 92 2 2e 84 42 6d 8a d5 64 6 3a 18 a8 75 cf} The file
>   'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\BindingRoot.cs' does
>   not exist. Looking in script documents for
>   'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\BindingRoot.cs'...
>   Looking in the projects for
>   'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\BindingRoot.cs'. The
>   file was not found in a project. Looking in directory 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\'... Looking in
>   directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\crt\src\vccorlib\'... Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'... Looking in
>   directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'... Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include'... The debug
>   source files settings for the active solution indicate that the
>   debugger will not ask the user to find the file:
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\BindingRoot.cs. The
>   debugger could not locate the source file
>   'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\BindingRoot.cs'.

In one of my controllers i have this:

```
IEmail Email = new Email();
Email.SendEmail("", "", "", true);
```

So ninject should change new Email to new MockEmail, but it doesn't.

Comment: @hutchonoid Even when i install that package for mvc 3 i still get the same problem.

Comment: What is the message / exception + message / stacktrace?

Comment: If you install the package as Install-package Ninject.MVC3, you should have a Ninject.MVC3 package. Is that the case?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is Ninject throwing an exception and complaining that it can't find the source code files in order to debug? I am not sure the Ninject package includes the pdb files.

Comment: @hutchonoid Yes i do have the package, the installation always succedees. dismissile, it's not throwing any exceptions, just a filedialog opens to select a class file of ninject. I'm pretty sure that the package has everything included to let ninject work?

Comment: I suppose you're getting an exception while debugging. The filedialog opens in the debugger (VS) so you can choose the source file to debug it. However, not finding the source files is not the issue causing the exception. You can click cancel and then the exception dialog should occur. Present us with that information.
If you want to debug it one of the easiest way would be to download the source code from the github repository (https://github.com/ninject/ninject) and then place it at c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I'm not getting any exceptions it just keeps asking me for a lot of different files where the file is located and it seems like it just repeatst because i have hold f11 for about 30 seconds.

Comment: So you are settings a breakpoint and want to debug, or what? I think you are having very general "trouble" with debugging and this is not ninject specific at all. One thing is certain: Ninject is not asking for any source files.
I would recommend: try pressing ESC instead of f11 when it asks you for the source files.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit Yes, i've added a breakpoint at the RegisterServices method. The escape key acts the same as the f11 key.

Comment: It's only asking you for source files because you are trying to debug something you don't have the source files for.
------------
What is it you are actually trying to accomplish? Do you actually want to debug or do you want to get your problem fixed? If you want to get your problem fixed, what is your problem?

Comment: See my first post, i've added some text to my information at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using the `new` operator you are bypassing your dependency injection container.
You can use constructor, property, method injection (https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns) or instruct the container to instanciate `IEMail` for you: `IResolutionRoot.Get<IEMail>()`.

I suggest you adapt your controller like follows:

```
public class Controller {

    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public Controller(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot) {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public void SendEmail() {
        this.resolutionRoot.Get<IEmail>().Send();
    }
}
```

Instead of using `IResolutionRoot` you could also use the ninject.extensions.factory and then inject `Func<IEmail> emailFactory` into the constructor of the controller.